# Google Play Developer API - editId parameter

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to use this api from google:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.apks/list

This endpoint requires two parameters:

1. packageName (Package name of the app)
2. editId (Identifier of the edit)

I understand what they mean by the `packageName`, but what do they mean with the `editId` parameter? Where do i find this `editId`? I literally have no clue.

Any tips would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Google Play "Edit" methods allow you to prepare a number of changes to your app and then deploy them all at once. You first need to insert an "Edit" [1] that will hold all the changes you want to make to the app. In other words, it is required to label all interactions by inserting an "Edit".

"When you first create an edit, the edit is a copy of the current deployed state of the app. You can then modify the edit by calling the Edits methods." [2]

[1] https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits/insert

[2] https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits